# Javascript: Checking object child array length even if object is not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, children

I would like to display some content only if an object's child array has elements in it. But sometimes the object itself is not defined so doing this fails if `object` or `object.child` is not present at the scope:

```
if(object.child.length){
    alert('hello world');
}
```

Which results in:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: object is not defined
```

So I have to add two additional if conditions to check if the object and it's child is defined or not:

```
if(typeof object !== 'undefined'){
    if(typeof object.child !== 'undefined'){
        if(object.child.length){
            alert('hello world');
        }
    }
}
```

Writing a function around this is problematic too:

```
function isset(value){ ... }
if(isset(object.child.length)({ ... } // <-- still raises error that object is not defined
```

Is there a cleaner, shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put a guard on:

```
if(object && object.child && object.child.length){
```

The above defends against `object` and `object.child` being `undefined` or `null` (or any other falsey value); it works because all non-`null` object references are truthy, so you can avoid the verbose `typeof object !== "undefined"` form. You may not need both of the guards above, if you know for sure that `object.child` will exist if `object` does. But having both is harmless.

It's worth noting that this is useful even when retrieving values, not just for testing them. For instance, suppose you have (or may not have!) `object.foo`, which contains a value you want to use.

```
var f = object && object.foo;
```

If `object` is falsey (`undefined` or `null` are the typical cases), then `f` will receive that falsey value (`undefined` or `null`). If `object` is truthy, `f` will receive the value of `object.foo`.

`||` is [curiously powerful](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) in a similar way.